# Why do for in loops rearrange some of the elements?

Tags: javascript, object, p5.js

So I have some code like this:

```js
var obj = {
    something: 10,
    1 : 15,
    2 : 20,
    3 : 25
};
for(var i in obj) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

That returns:
1,
2,
3,
something

Why is the first element moved to the end?

Comment: the specs says so ... index like values comes first.

Comment: It's best if you don't rely on object property order. It *could* be predictable but it's also very easily disturbed. Use at least a map which guarantees insertion order. It might be even better if you use a different data structure like an array to maintain the order you expect.